# Sitecore Glass Mapper Get All Siblings

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I am trying to get all items at the current item level. I am using Glass Mapper `SitecoreQuery` for the same. I am able to get the current item but not able to map all siblings

```cs
public class TestModel:BaseModel
{
    [SitecoreQuery("../*")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Model1> Siblings { get; set; }
}

[SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
public class Model1 : BaseModel
{

}
```

Base Model has all the required fields and correctly mapped. I am actually trying to display all items at the level of current item.

Comment: Try to add second parameter to `SitecoreQuery` :  `IsRelative = true` like that: `[SitecoreQuery("../*", IsRelative = true)]`

Comment: Are you trying to get all items at the same level or siblings only (i.e. excluding the current item)?

Comment: IsRelative at the end is important, it tells Glass.Mapper to execute the query relative to the item the class represents. Also you should add `[SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]` above your TestModel class.

Comment: Thanks . "IsRelative = true"  worked for me .

Comment: @Deb I'm glad it helped. Comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add second parameter to `SitecoreQuery` : `IsRelative = true` like that:

```cs
[SitecoreQuery("../*", IsRelative = true)]
public virtual IEnumerable<Model1> Siblings { get; set; }
```

It tells Sitecore to start query at your item level instead of starting at the tree root.

You can find more information in the [Official Sitecore Glass Mapper Tutorial](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial7)